# How do I assign numbers 10 through 16 a letter in this hex/binary table?

Tags: javascript

```
var count = -1;
var countLetter = "";

for (outer = 0; outer < 2; outer++) {
    for (inner = 0; inner < 2; inner++) {
        for (third = 0; third < 2; third++) {
            for (fourth = 0; fourth < 2; fourth++) {

                count++;
                countLetter = count;
                document.write(countLetter + "|" + "" + outer + "" + inner + "" + third + "" + fourth + ".</br>");


            }
        }
    }
}
```

I attempted to add an `if(count)=10{counterLetter="A"}` and so on but this didn't work, either broke the code or ended up doing something wacky. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: `if(count)=10` is not the correct syntax. You mean `if(count == 10)`, right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's the end goal?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Number.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) you may write:

```
countLetter = count.toString(16).toUpperCase();
```

The snippet:

```js
var count = -1;
var countLetter = "";

for (outer = 0; outer < 2; outer++) {
  for (inner = 0; inner < 2; inner++) {
    for (third = 0; third < 2; third++) {
      for (fourth = 0; fourth < 2; fourth++) {
        count++;
        countLetter = count.toString(16).toUpperCase();
        document.write(countLetter + "|" + "" + outer + "" + inner + "" + third + "" + fourth + ".</br>");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A shorter version:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  document.write(i.toString(16).toUpperCase() + "|" + ("000" + i.toString(2)).slice(-4) + ".</br>");
}
```